# Browser can only open Google and MSN

Tags: networking, router, vlan

I have setup vlan on my router using DD-WRT. Everything works fine except vlan2 computer can only visit google.com and msn.com (they got unable to display the page when visit amazon or ebay). When I tried to ping www.yahoo.com in for vlan2. I got response but the ping is a bit high (500~600), but it shouldn't have problem opening webpage eventually. I was wondering if anyone had the same problem before. Thanks a lot!

```
Main Router: Linksys WRT54GS  V7.2 (with DD-WRT)
port 1 is configured for vlan2
vlan1 computers
DHCP enable
ip: 192.168.1.10~192.168.1.20
Default gateway:192.168.1.1
subnet:255.255.255.0


Secondary router: Linksys WRT54G V5.0 (none DD-WRT)
connect to main router port1
vlan2 computers
DHCP disable
ip: 192.168.2.5~192.168.2.10.
Default gateway:192.168.2.1
subnet:255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be a DNS issue, Try flushing the DNS from command line using `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: Thanks squillman. I tried but still not working.